# Rendering HTML Within <script> Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm injecting some HTML into my page using this code:

```
    <script>    
window.onload = function() {
  addHeader();
};
    </script>

<script>function addHeader(){$("#header-nav-studio").after('<li id="header-nav-products" class="has-subnav"> <a href="/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000025/Apparel_Pricing">Pricing  <span class="arrow-down"></span> </a> <div class="header-subnav"> <ul> <li><a href="http://livecustom.com/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000025/Apparel_Pricing"> Apparel Pricing</a></li><li><a href="https://livecustom.com/LiveCustom/Full_Color_Vinyl_Stickers-Products/1000036"> Sticker Pricing</a></li><li><a href="https://livecustom.com/LiveCustom/Pinback_Buttons-Products/1000039"> Pinback Button Pricing</a></li></ul> </div></li>')}</script>
```

It works, loads everything directly after the "#header-nav-studio" DIV. Only problem is, it's not rendering the HTML within the script properly. It's supposed to generate a "Pricing" dropdown menu. Instead it only works as a link. You can see the example [HERE](http://livecustom.com)

Is there a way to load the html properly within the script tag or load it from an external source?  Thanks so much!

Comment: You're declaring a function `addHeader` but you are never calling it. Add `addHeader()` at the end of the script tag.

Comment: @Olian04 sorry i do call for it onload. just forgot to add it in the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to bind `mouseover` event on DOM element you have dynamically added that triggers your submenu appearance.

On `li` element with class `has-subnav`, there is `mouseover` event listener, that toggles css class `active` on it.

You need to change your javascript, so the event is attached even for dynamically created elements. You can use `$.on()` on parent selector to attach handler.

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.has-subnav', function() {
   $(this).addClass('.active');
});
//and to remove class on mouseout
$('body').on('mouseover', '.has-subnav', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('.active');
});
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me how youd implement that? i'll give it a shot!

Comment: @DennisMenzel, I have expanded my answer with code example.

Comment: I see.  Would I add that to a separate script or the current script?

Comment: still can't seem to get it. It's worth noting on this page, the same exact code is implemented in the body of the HTML and works perfectly.
https://livecustom.com/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000024/Test_Page_Part_Deux

Comment: @DennisMenzel, look at source: view-source:https://livecustom.com/LiveCustom/Stores/Page/1000024/Test_Page_Part_Deux  on that sample page, you have placed the call for `addHeader()` first within `window.onload` function line #170, then you added additional code below line #311 `$("#header-nav-studio").after('<li id="header-nav-jeff" class="has-subnav">...);` , the second portion is called before DOM is fully loaded, since it is not within the `$(document).ready();` nor `window.onload()`. And because of that, it triggers before the script that attaches mouseover event listener, making it work.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you shared, the pricing menu item has id same as products menu item. Two nodes having same id can have unexpected results. I would say change the id first to say 'header-nav-pricing' and try your code again.

Comment: Tried that. had no effect one way or the other

Comment: Also you have to bind the `mouseover` to the new menu item. You can add it using `$(document).on('mouseover', 'header-nav-pricing', function(){ //your function })`